# Logging and exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception, logging

I'm currently coding my first larger script which is a console based GUI where the user selects options by entering numbers to start several tasks:

[image: See this example screenshot.]

I've recently implemented a lot of error handling to prevent the window from closing if something goes wrong in the background. I'm a little bit confused whether or not my approach is correct.

The basic structure of my code is as following:

There is a function `read_excel()` which loads some Excel files with pandas:

```py
def read_excel(excel_path):
    
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, encoding="utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError('Unable to load assignment file, maybe choose custom')
        return

    # do stuff....

    if not all(len(x) == len(signalnames) for x in [frequencies, cans]):
        raise ValueError('Frequency and can number must be given for every signal in assignment file!')
    else:
        logging.info("Successfully loaded assignment file")

   return signalnames, frequencies, group_names, cans, can_paths
```

This function is then used together with others in the function `ft_14()` which is called by the GUI:

```py
def ft_14(files, draft assignement_path):
    try:
        signalnames, frequencies, group_names, cans, can_paths = read_excel(assignement_path)
    except (ValueError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return

        # do stuff..

        try:
            wb.save(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(files[0]), "FT.14_results.xlsx"))
            wb.close()
        except Exception:
            logging.error('Unable to save report excel')
```

So my attempt is to raise exceptions in the backend and then except them in functions which are called by the GUI and use logging to display them for the user. So my question is if this approach is the correct way to use exceptions and logging together or if there is a smarter way, because calling:

```py
try:
    # some function()
except Exection as e:
    logging.error(e)
```

doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Your approach seems sound to me. If a function fails, raising an exception is a very pythonic way of doing things, while other languages (such as C or Go) would return errors. Just one recommendation, create your own exception types by sub-classing `Exception` and use them in the `try: ... except ...` clauses instead of the generic `Exception`. My recommendation is to have a package level exception and then a bunch of exceptions that that inherit from it: `class MyPackageException(Exception): pass` and then `class CertainErrorTypeException(MyPackageException): pass`

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! I now implemented my own exception class wich directly loggs to the current logger. It looks a lot cleaner now.

Comment: It helps a lot with the clarity but it also has another benefit. When doing a `try ... except ...` clause on a generic `Exception` you will be capturing errors that you didnt want to and handle them as if they were the errors you were looking for and that will give you a lot of headaches until you realize that what was logged as a, for example, value out of bonds error was a `TypeError` because you called a function with a `str` instead of an `int`. This tree-like structure with a root error for your package and as many layers and errors as you want inheritign from it really helps debuging.

Comment: Just an aside, but it's not a GUI, by definition, it's a console/text-based UI, i.e. a CLI.

Comment: I notice you're catching an exception, then raising a different but similar exception, and then catch that elsewhere. I would consider catch it once, log it immediately, and then use "raise" to re-raise the same exception with whatever info it originally had.

Comment: Is there an indentation error between your "read the file" code and your "write the file" code? Perhaps those could be self-contained functions, to simplify your code.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Exactly that was the part wich didint seem right to mee, catching Exceptions and raising the same again. But based on Adirios comment i worked around this by implementing my own Exception wich logs to the logger. And yes there is an indentaition error here sorry :).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Since we're nitpicking... :) It's not a CLI because it is interactive and doesn't actually use the command line. I guess it's a [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted at the end, which makes you uncomfortable, is correct in that it does what it says it will do. If there is an exception, it logs the error.

The concern is that it also handles the exception. In many cases, you don't want to change anything else in the exception handling process -- you just want to log, and let the exception propagate normally.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def fn(x):
    try:
        return x / 0
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(str(e))
        raise e
    
print ("let's do something risky")
try:
    fn(20)
except Exception as e:
    pass
print ("it has been done")
```

Notice how fn(x) can detect and handle exceptions, then re-raise them as if it had not done anything to the exception at all? You do that with "raise" and no arguments.

In your first code example, you catch an exception, and then raise a completely different exception, which happens to be of the same type:

```
except FileNotFoundError:
    raise FileNotFoundError('Unable to load assignment file, maybe choose custom')
```

This can be fair game if you want to hide info, for example if the exception has internal details you do not want to expose to the outside. But you don't know what info you lost by replacing the exception entirely with a new instance. But none of those is "right" or "wrong," they're just choices you make with how to handle exceptions. (edit: it is good practice to handle them eventually or document what it can throw, but we're off topic)

None of that matters to the logger. You could have logged it right there and re-raised. You could log the original exception, then raise the sanitized version. You could handle it there, log it, and not raise (as the example you posted). The logger doesn't care what you do with the exception. If you want it logged, log it immediately.